# How to clean up SSISDB history for a specific job only

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. My `ssisdb` has a job that runs every minute.  Standard retention cleanup would not effectively trim that job because it can cause growth in far less time than a standard daily job. Therefore I need to run a different maintenance cleanup on that job vs other jobs.

I am concerned it might cause problems with ssisdb if I just randomly delete lines, or have a job randomly delete lines from just the apparent worse culprit tables (event_messages, event_message_context)  Is there any tool or advice for how to clean up based on a single job?  Is there is an official stored procedure for cleaning up these tables?